# Set variable inside void function

Tags: c#

When I press the button, I want to assign the current time (start temp value) to the start time variable in the same class. How can i make it?

```
public class Simulator
{
TimeSpan start Time;
    private void b_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string tempDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
       TimeSpan startTemp = TimeSpan.Parse(tempDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: `TimeSpan start Time;` is not valid C#. Did you mean to write `TimeSpan startTime;`?

Comment: What have you tried so far & what error messages do you get? Really what I am saying here is have you tried assigning startTemp to your variable - because that should work.

Comment: The conversion to string and then parsing of the string is unnecessary. Just use `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`;

Comment: I would also ask what are you trying to achieve with your code - the TimeSpan class should be used for storing a time interval - not storing a particular time.

Comment: @PaulF: I assume the code is trying to get the timespan since latest midnight.

Comment: @PalleDue: I just wanted to make sure that OP understood that - as the name of the field is "_startTime_" then either it is badly named or it is being used to store a time - which is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
TimeSpan startTemp = TimeSpan.Parse(tempDate);
```

You can assign to the class member directly:

```
this.startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(tempDate);
```

Your member declaration seems to be incorrect...

```
TimeSpan startTime;
```